# Async FTP when having connection errors

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-4.0, ftpwebrequest

I made a windows service, that uploads all the files (pictures) that are put into a folder.

The ftp works async, and was based on the msdn code.

All works fine, until I unplug the network cable.

The ftp method is supposed to catch the error and return a false bool. Then I move the file to a failed folder, and it continues with the next file.
When the 3rd file is reached, the WaitOne action never stops, and the EndGetStreamCallback is never reached. I really don't know what is going on.
After this the service also becomes unresponsive until I restart it.

The file handler:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            AsynchronousFtpUpLoader ftp = new AsynchronousFtpUpLoader();
            foreach (string file in files) {
                var result = ftp.Upload(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftp_host"] + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftp_path"] + file.Replace(path, "").Substring(1), file);
                if (!result) { 
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

The AsynchronousFtpUpLoader :

```
public class AsynchronousFtpUpLoader
    {
        public bool Upload(string sTarget,string file)
        {
            bool succeed = false;
            // Create a Uri instance with the specified URI string. 
            // If the URI is not correctly formed, the Uri constructor 
            // will throw an exception.
            ManualResetEvent waitObject;

            Uri target = new Uri(sTarget);
            string fileName = file;
            FtpState state = new FtpState();

            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(target);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftp_user"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftp_password"]);

            // Store the request in the object that we pass into the 
            // asynchronous operations.
            state.Request = request;
            state.FileName = fileName;

            // Get the event to wait on.
            waitObject = state.OperationComplete;

            // Asynchronously get the stream for the file contents.
            request.BeginGetRequestStream(
                new AsyncCallback(EndGetStreamCallback),
                state
            );

            // Block the current thread until all operations are complete.
            waitObject.WaitOne();

            // The operations either completed or threw an exception. 
            if (state.OperationException != null)
            {
                Log.writeLog("ERROR","FTP error", sTarget.Substring(0, sTarget.IndexOf("_")).Substring(sTarget.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1), sTarget);
                Log.writeError(state.OperationException.ToString() + (state.OperationException.InnerException != null ? state.OperationException.InnerException.ToString() : ""), sTarget);
                //throw state.OperationException;
            }
            else
            {
                succeed = true;
                Console.WriteLine("The operation completed - {0}", state.StatusDescription);
            }

            return succeed;
        }
        private static void EndGetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            FtpState state = (FtpState)ar.AsyncState;

            Stream requestStream = null;
            // End the asynchronous call to get the request stream. 
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Opened the stream");
                using(requestStream = state.Request.EndGetRequestStream(ar)){
                    // Copy the file contents to the request stream. 
                    const int bufferLength = 2048;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
                    int count = 0;
                    int readBytes = 0;
                    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(state.FileName))
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            readBytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                            count += readBytes;
                        }
                        while (readBytes != 0);
                        Console.WriteLine("Writing {0} bytes to the stream.", count);
                        // IMPORTANT: Close the request stream before sending the request.
                        requestStream.Close();
                        stream.Close();
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Closed the stream");
                // Asynchronously get the response to the upload request.
                state.Request.BeginGetResponse(
                    new AsyncCallback(EndGetResponseCallback),
                    state
                );
            }
            // Return exceptions to the main application thread. 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not get the request stream.");
                state.OperationException = e;
                state.OperationComplete.Set();

                if (requestStream != null) {
                    requestStream.Close();
                }
                return;
            }

        }

        // The EndGetResponseCallback method   
        // completes a call to BeginGetResponse. 
        private static void EndGetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            FtpState state = (FtpState)ar.AsyncState;
            FtpWebResponse response = null;
            try
            {
                response = (FtpWebResponse)state.Request.EndGetResponse(ar);
                response.Close();
                state.StatusDescription = response.StatusDescription;
                // Signal the main application thread that  
                // the operation is complete.
                state.OperationComplete.Set();
            }
            // Return exceptions to the main application thread. 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error getting response.");
                state.OperationException = e;
                state.OperationComplete.Set();

                if (response != null) {
                    response.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if this would matter or not, but in my do loop where I'm writing to the request stream buffer I also have a line such as `if (readBytes == 0) continue;` after your `readBytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);` line.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Code based on the same MSDN example, but enhanced to work over SSL/TLS.
Files can successfully uploads hours or day but sometimes hangs in environment with bad internet connection - main thread blocked forever.
Reproduced the problem using http://jagt.github.io/clumsy/ and debugged it. It seems that when uploading bytes finished we stucked on closing requeststream here

```
                        // IMPORTANT: Close the request stream before sending the request.
                    requestStream.Close();
```

When we call this, FtpWebRequest closed the uploading connection and waits operation to be done. In terms of FtpWebRequest, stage must be changed to ReleaseConnection. This stage change is done when FTP server send message over control channel, that uploading is done (when we closed binary connection). For some reason it never happens. May be due network errors ftp client doesn't receive message from server and waits forever.

Possible solutions:

1. Implement watchdog that abort connection after timeout on requestStream.Close()
2. Seems like with KeepAlive = false it may works more stable (not fully tested)